# Typo3 get link parent page on child page in html template

Tags: menu, navigation, typo3

Hello I have a sub navigation

```
lib.subnavigation = COA 
lib.subnavigation {
  10 = HMENU
  10 {
    entryLevel = 2
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        expAll = 1
        NO {                          
            doNotLinkIt = 1
            #wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
            stdWrap.cObject = CASE
            stdWrap.cObject {
                key.field = doktype
                default = TEXT
                default {           
                    typolink.parameter.field = uid
                    typolink.additionalParams.insertData = 1
                    field = title
                    #wrap = <span>|</span>
                    stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
                }
                # 4 = shortcut
                4 = TEXT
                #4.wrap = <span>|</span>
                4 {
                    field = title
                    typolink.parameter.field = shortcut
                    typolink.ATagBeforeWrap = 1
                }
                # 3 = external url
                3 = TEXT
                3 {
                    field = title
                    typolink.parameter.field = url
                    typolink.extTarget.field = target
                }       
            }                                                   
        }
        ACT = 1
        ACT {
            doNotLinkIt = 1
            #wrapItemAndSub = <li class="home-lnk active">|</li>
            stdWrap.cObject = COA
            stdWrap.cObject {
                1 = TEXT
                1.wrap = <a  href="
                1.typolink.parameter.data = field:uid
                1.typolink.returnLast = url
                2 = TEXT
                2.wrap = " class="active">
                3 = TEXT
                3.data = field:title
                4 = TEXT
                4.wrap = </a>
            }
        }
    }                       
}
```

I need to get a link to the parent page in the HTML template, how can I do this? Through what variable can I get a link to the parent page?

My html template:

```
<f:layout name="DefaultLayout" />
<f:section name="content">
    <f:format.raw>{content_100}</f:format.raw>      
    <div class="page-title-wrap">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="page-title">Regionalstelle <f:format.raw>{pagetitle_sub}</f:format.raw></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mnu-third-wrap">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="mnu-third">
                <f:format.raw>{subnavigation}</f:format.raw>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
    <f:format.raw>{content_0}</f:format.raw>
</f:section>
```

The variable subnavigation contains all the links to the sub-menu.
I need to make a page-title link to the parent page, thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: you should clean up your question. the submenu distracts the focus, but your main question is: "`how do I get a link to the parent page in fluid?`"

Comment: aside from that your typoscript can get some optimization (for `ACT` you define default behaviour, but very complicated  and with strange usage of `.wrap` (no split)). you have variable `subnavigation` which gets filled with a copy or reference of `lib.subnavigation` (eitehr use `temp.subnavigation` for copy) or call `lib.subnavigation`directly in your fluid (`<f:cObject typoscriptObjectpath="lib.subnavigation" />`). shorten your format VHs: `{content_0->f:format.raw()}`

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

depending on the context you have always a `data` record. for contentlements it's the tt_content record, and for the page it is `pages`.
The parent of the current page can be identified by the field `pid` (Page-/Parent-ID).

so you can build a link to the parent page like:

```
<f:link.page pageUid="{data.pid}">parent page</f:link.page>
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you'd replace `typolink.parameter.field = uid` with `typolink.parameter.field = pid` in the TS

Comment: I need to change the block <div class="page-title-wrap">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="page-title">Regionalstelle <f:format.raw>{pagetitle_sub}</f:format.raw></div>
        </div>
    </div> to <a> </ a> with a link to the parent_Page

Comment: OK, then you need to define a cObject in TS like:  
`lib.linkToParent = TEXT  
lib.linkToParent.data = page:pid`  
Rendering:  
`<f:link.typolink parameter='<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.linkToParent" />'>Regionalstelle <f:format.raw>{pagetitle_sub}</f:format.raw></f:link.typolink>`

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot.

Answer (score -1):

The answer of Bernd Wilke is only correct in context of a page template. For content elements {data.pid} contains the page uid of the current page, not the uid of the parent page.
Inside content elements you could use the vhs viewhelpers.

To use the value directly in the template:

```
<v:page.info field="pid" />
```

Or inside another viewhelper, <f:form> in this example:

```
<f:form pageUid="{v:page.info(field: 'pid')}">
```

Comment: The question is about a menu. Why should this appear in a content element? And `v:page.info` will only work if you have vhs installed though.